# Cut facebook api image url

Tags: php, regex, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have url like this:

```
https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t1.0-9/s130x130/10424323_10152876971487952_1546612319458109056_n.jpg?oh=10e3a6ac938854989e6d5fe3b2682e56&oe=54D25E8E
```

How to cut `/s130x130` via js or php? Here can be not only `/s130x130` (`/s250x250`, `/s340x239`, etc.). URL must be like

```
https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t1.0-9/10424323_10152876971487952_1546612319458109056_n.jpg?oh=10e3a6ac938854989e6d5fe3b2682e56&oe=54D25E8E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex Patterns for this.

```
$url = 'https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t1.0-9/s130x130/10424323_10152876971487952_1546612319458109056_n.jpg?oh=10e3a6ac938854989e6d5fe3b2682e56&oe=54D25E8E';
$new_url = preg_replace('|(/s\d{1,3}x\d{1,3})[^/]|','',$url);
echo $new_url;
```